# Lookup Positive and Negative Totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day

I am working on a Debtors book. I found that in my "BALANCE" column there are Positive and Negative amounts on the same client column "CLIENT NUMBER" that can balance out for the Pos total and Neg Total = 0. Is there a way that I can indicate that in a "Status" Column i.e. If For the Same Client "CLIENT NUMBER" Column there is a Positive Amount ($2000) and a Negative Amount (-$2000) in "BALANCE" Column "STATUS" = 'Recon'

Thanks

**Why would I get a Negative for this Question??

Comment: So? Any questions? Any code?

Comment: Is there a way that I can indicate that in a "Status" Column i.e. If For the Same Client "CLIENT NUMBER" Column there is a Positive Amount ($2000) and a Negative Amount (-$2000) in "BALANCE" Column "STATUS" = 'Recon'. Was wondering if this can be done with a CASE?

Comment: So you want to indicate that a client amount is not zero because there isn't any amounts, but zero because it balances each other out?
Yes this can be done - any suggestions yourself?

Comment: (To answer your question about the downvoting: Your question is unclear and does not show any research effort of yours. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That's just the problem I don't know how to approach this. I have never had to reference something this way. I am not really SQL "expert"...but IF SQL was written specially for me I would have had a line like this: For each CLIENT in CLIENT NUMBER Column that has a NEGATIVE BALANCE - have a look if that same CLIENT exist with a POSITIVE BALANCE that can = the AMOUNT to ZERO. IF this statement = TRUE then on POSITIVE LINE and NEGATIVE LINE = 'Recon' END AS 'Status'. I had the data in excel and had to get the answer through formulas, would much rather get same answer straight from source.

Comment: Maybe a for each code can work? I will give that a try and post my progress.

Comment: ** Do you think it's a good approach to first make the "NEGATIVE" a "POSITIVE" and the Group by the same amount?

Comment: Put all the code you've given in a comment into the question itself, that will help. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this :

```
select Client_number , 'Recon'
FROM yrtableName 
GROUP BY Client_number
HAVING SUM(balance) = 0
```

Comment: Hi Rishabh, Thanks a lot for your help. This is what I needed and it sorted out my problem.